# Eclipse - Unexpected exception when trying to create Web Service based on a WSDL file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to create a Web Service in Eclipse Java EE IDE (Helios Service Release 2, Windows 7 32-bit) based on a WSDL file, but when I click "finish" in the creation wizard I always get:

**IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.**

```
(details: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.creation.ui.widgets.skeleton.SkeletonConfigWidgetDefaultingCommand.getOutputJavaFolder(SkeletonConfigWidgetDefaultingCommand.java:86)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.creation.ui.widgets.skeleton.SkeletonConfigWidgetDefaultingCommand.execute(SkeletonConfigWidgetDefaultingCommand.java:47)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
      at **...**)
```

I'm 100% sure that WSDL file is correct - the error happens no matter how trivial etc. the file is.

The way I'm doing it:

1. create a general project and add a new WSDL file to it;
2. File -> New -> Other -> Web Services -> Web Service
3. In the Web Service wizard, I choose "Top down Java Bean Service" and select the appropriate WSDL file.
4. When I click Next or Finish, the above exception occurs and no source files are generated.

I'm using Tomcat 6.0 server (localhost), but I suppose that's irrelevant.

Any tips on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just downloaded helios, and followed your steps using this wsdl http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceAntTask/srcfiles/AreaService.wsdl it generated fine. You could try doing the same, and if it works, it's probably something to do with your wsdl.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response; however, no, it doesn't work, the same exception with this WSDL. I actually had some friends try different WSDLs on their machines (same Eclipse version, same everything) and it works just fine, but fails for me for some reason. I updated Java, Java EE, checked for Eclipse Updates and still nothing.

Comment: The reason for this seemed to be messed up workspaces. I removed workspaces first from Eclipse Project Explorer, then from the filesystem. I then recreated the workspace and got no exceptions thrown.

Comment: Odd. Glad you solved your problem though.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by going to

> Preferences -> Web Services -> Server and Runtime

and changing the *`Web Service Runtime`* from "**Apache Axis**" to "**Apache Axis2**".

Comment: this didnt work for me. Can you suggest any more solution?

Comment: its work, but how if i want use cxf ? i have cxf in my eclipse.

Comment: This didnt work for me either

Answer (score 5):

Create an empty dynamic web project, copy paste the WSDL, and generate the code from there, then copy the generated files into your project, it worked for me this way.

I know this is annoying, but I could solve it like that,especially if you have more than one WSDL file, for me; I could generate the server code for the first WSDL, but not for the rest.

Best regards.

Comment: this ended up working for me.  not the best "solution", since it doesn't really address whatever workspace issues exist that caused the need for this workaround in the first place, but still, this works.  I ended up running the web service client generation tool with all options I needed, and didn't even have to create a project.  I just created an empty workspace, went through the wizard, and then copied generated code to my actual workspace, where things worked perfectly.  thanks for adding your perspective on this, basselkh!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused due to existence of hyphens in the WSDL URL. Do you have any '-'(hyphen's) in your WSDL URL, if yes, thats the problem. 
Please check --> [IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK66468)